# HTMLCollection returning null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have already looked at other stackoverflow posts and none of them fix my error.

[Trying to get the divs inside the outer div with class name "CodeMirror-code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhsjz.png)

I'm building a chrome extension that directly modifies the html content of a specific webpage and when I call

`const variable = document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-code');`

`console.log(variable);`

`console.log("Length:", variable.length);`

the output is: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMiKC.png)

Now, when I try to call the first item of HTML collection like

`variable.item(0)`

this returns undefined or null

Other solutions says that you should surround the code in window.onload function in order for the DOM elements to be loaded in.
I did this, and there was no change.
Is there any way I can fix this error?

Update:
[This is what is inside the HTML collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN2Tv.png)

Comment: If the length of variable is 0, it's normal that `variable.item(0)` returns undefined or null. Are you sure that you have HTML elements with the class "CodeMirror-code" because otherwise it makes no sense that the length of the variable is 0

Comment: Hi, I updated a screenshot to include what's in the HTML collection. It's definitely not empty but still returns 0 for some reason?

Comment: Why not share the piece of HTML you're trying to capture? It'll make it easier to understand and spot what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your code in a set interval function within window.onLoad and add some delay (like 2000 for 2 seconds). The only thing that gives HtML collection null is the loading latency of dom elements. If adding delay is still not helping then try to retrace the parents of your div and see till what point your js code is able to catch the expected div. Then check whether its the problem with load time or scope of the code.

Comment: But, when I look into the HTML collection, it's not empty and is fully loaded as the newly added screenshot indicates?

Comment: Try adding your js code in <script> tags right below your concerned div or maybe under the same parent. If the div has been loaded then there is no way document.getElementsByClassName() would give u null.

Comment: You were right, it's the timeout that makes it work. However, is there a way to make the time out whenever the length > 0, instead of a specific timing like 400ms?

Comment: I'm afraid not because it depends on how that div id being rendered in your html. If its being made after a data fetch or some processing over a variable or data then you'll have to put your JS code right after that. Though window.onLoad should have fixed it. In jQuery we have document.ready which execute code after the document is done loading but as I said before it all depends on how and what is rendering that div in question